# Execute all actions of first Saga before executing second Saga actions

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I have generator function in redux saga as below:

```
function* updateLanguage() {

    // some api call;

    yield put(changeSkillsList());

    yield put(fetchingSkills());
}



function* changeSkillsListGenerator() {
    yield put(action1());
    yield put(action2());
    yield put(action3());
    yield put(action4());
}



function* fetchingSkillsGenerator() {
    yield put(actionA());
    yield put(actionB());
    yield put(actionC());
    yield put(actionD());
}
```

I want to execute actions as below: **all actions of first yield put then second**

```
action1
action2
action3
action4
actionA
actionB
actionC
actionD
```

*But it's executing as below:*

```
action1
actionA
action2
action3
actionB
actionC
actionD
action4
```

**I want to dispatch all actions of first saga before moving to second.**

**Kindly suggest solution for this.**
**Any advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps simply make `fetchingSkillsGenerator` to run only after `action4`:

```
function* fetchingSkillsGenerator() {
    yield take(action4.type); // this line forces saga to wait until action4 dispatched 
    yield put(actionA());
    ...
```

[Helpfull doc link](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/FutureActions.html).